# jQuery hover menu link-items and change image

Tags: jquery, css, each

i have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/8rns6whp/3/) jQuery function for [my site](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/). But i can't find the solution for the last step.

Look at the CSS structure of the menu. With a plugin (Magento admin) you can built the menu. I can give a CSS class (`links1`, `links2`, `links3` etc) to `<div class="grid-column grid-column3 links1 ">`, to split the menu-items in different columns. I changed the script with jQuery.each like:

`var linkIDX = $(this).index() + $(this).parent().parent().attr("class").each(function(id,val){});`

To reach the `<div>` with the CSS class (`links1`, `links2`, `links3` etc).

**My question:** What do i have to change in my CSS to change the image? Now i have for the first link:

```
.imageChange0 {
 content:url("http://www.belmondo.nl/media/catalog/product/cache/1/cover_image/190x190/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/babyboekcover_262px_262px_2.png") !important; 
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Changing an image via jQuery should be possible with the following

```
$(yourImageSelector).attr('src', newImagePath);
```

Is there a reason, why you want to change it via CSS? Just asking, because I've never seen it before :)

Comment: I thought in my case its necessary. Look at [my script](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/8rns6whp/3/). In my case i can give a css class `links1`, `links2` to the parent parent `<div>`. And because the menu plugin generates more then 1 css class i cannot use just `.parent().parent()` but i have to use `.each`. But which css class i have to connect to this? thanks

Comment: As far as i know (and read for the img case), `content` can be used for pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after`.
If you want a CSS only solution (for setting the image) I would do as an background image for the `#image-li`

Comment: but did you had a look at the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/8rns6whp/3/). There basically its working. But in my case i have more the 1 CSS selector class in the `<div class="grid-column grid-column3 links1 ">`. My question is: what CSS class do i have to use to change the img: `.imageChange0...???` thanks!

Comment: In CSS you can select an element with multiple classes as well. For the div of your last comment: `.grid-column.grid-column3.links1`

Oh, and Firefox does not show any images ;)

Comment: Do you have an idea how to reconstruct [it](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/8rns6whp/3/) with your suggestion: `$(yourImageSelector).attr('src', newImagePath);`. Important is that we have to divide the links in separate columns... But in my case `<ul id="example">` = `<div class="grid-column grid-column3 links1 ">` Thanks a lot for your assistance

Comment: hai do you have a suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would set the image name as an attribute for the link element, such as `data-name="image.png"`. Then you can build up your image path from that.

If you want a specif class out of a list of classes, I think you have to remove all common classes vis JS first. Identification is easier, when you use just one class, or an id or other attribute, from which you know, that it is unique.